Trying to rotate an image with the javascript canvas
enter image description hereI'm trying to make a rock spawn at a random rotation, for variation, but it is always offset by a certain amount that changes based on the direction, which messes up collision.
Rock.prototype.draw = function () {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.rect(
      this.collider.x - scrollX,
      this.collider.y - scrollY,
      this.collider.w,
      this.collider.h
    );
    ctx.stroke();

    ctx.translate(
      -this.w * 0.1 + this.x - scrollX,
      -this.h * 0.2 + this.y - scrollY
    );
    ctx.rotate(this.dir);
    ctx.drawImage(rockImage, 0, 0, this.w, this.h);
    ctx.rotate(-this.dir);
    ctx.translate(
      -(-this.w * 0.1 + this.x - scrollX),
      -(-this.h * 0.2 + this.y - scrollY)
    );
    ctx.closePath();
};

This is the current function to draw a rock. I was expecting it to be centered, but instead, it looks like this:

(The important part of that duplicate is to offset by half the width, you are currently rotating around the top left corner instead of the centre)

Alright thank you
